# RDLC expression error when dividing two numbers

Tags: rdlc

I have written an expression to get gross profit margin as follows.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1>0 AND Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossSalesDataSet")-1>0,ROUND(((Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1)/(Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossSalesDataSet")-1))*100,2) & "%","0.00")
```

it shows #Error when the Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1 and the Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1 has zero. I have handled the zero values. Someone please help  men to find the error

Answer (score 0):

It is your Conversion related error. You need to convert **AuguestValue** to your desired any numeric data type if this not in numeric. Try with following expression

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1>0 AND Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossSalesDataSet")-1>0,ROUND(((Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossProfitDataSet")-1)/(Sum(Fields!AugustValue.Value, "GrossSalesDataSet")-1))*100,2) & "%","0.00")
```